# How to remove skin from field corn

Tags: food-science

I'm trying to nixtamalize field corn. The kernels swell but the skins don't come off even with vigorous rubbing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you can tell us what you are actually doing - i.e. your method, then you might get a sensible answer, as it stands all you tell us is that you are treating with an alkali, but not what sort, what concentration, how long, variety of corn etc.